# Is there any implementation of xdg-utils on MSYS2 or Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, msys, xdg

Recently I have a project which need to to use tools in xdg-utils. However in order to make it compatible with windows, is there any implementation of this project on Windows?

If there is not, is there any implementation of xdg-open?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin has a [Package Search](https://cygwin.com/packages/) link to find packages:

[image]

Source [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=xdg-utils&arch=x86_64)

Comment: Thanks so much, Can I use pacman -S to install it on MSYS2?

Comment: @MartinS.Victory No idea. I only use Cygwin.